# how to run 2 commands using one system() function in c++

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, cmd, c++-cli

I want to execute 2 cmd commands in one system () function c++ but one cmd command passed as a concatenation:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

            System::String^ managedString = textBox1->Text; 

             msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
    std::string standardString = context.marshal_as<std::string>(managedString);

    std::string s2 = "yara64 -r test.yara " + standardString;

    system(s2.c_str() && "pause");

}
```

this code doesn't work. this works only if I remove "pause" command. How to execute exactly with "pause" command in one system ()?

Please help me.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: You really should not be using `system`.

Comment: put the && and the pause in the std::string first. Instead of trying to combine char arrays.

Comment: `&&` doesnt concatenate strings, it is the logical and operator that returns a boolean

Comment: Can you wrap the `&&` in quotes so it will be interpreted by the executing environment as a single command instead of C interpreting it as a logical and? `std::string s2 = "yara64 -r test.yara " + standardString + " && pause"`?? Ah, people beat me to it.

Comment: @Dragon14: I fail to see how that could compile.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Bull.

Comment: **−1** This is **not real code**. There's no way that could compile. Voting to close as lacking reproducible example.

Comment: My code compiles. People please don't write negative comments. I just showed only part of my code, where the problem exists, in order to simplify the question. Please remove unfair minuses. If you want to see the full code please write me private messages. Or ask here and I can put the code here.  And especial thanks to Hydranix who first gave me correct answer.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: @ Cheers and hth. - Alf:   please remove unfair minuses. Now, it is your turn

Comment: @Cheers:  Ok? so I am waiting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the "&&" part of the string itself.

```
std::string s2 = "yara64 -r test.yara " + standardString + "&& pause";
system(s2.c_str());
```

Comment: **−1** "learn to avoid system() at all costs" introduces severe costs for the cozy feeling of belonging to some unthinking herd. It's balderdash.

Comment: @Cheers There's always a better way to accomplish every situation that `system()` can be used in. Whens the last time you used `system()` in your own code?

Comment: Re "There's always a better way [than `system`", no, system-specific DIY code that accomplishes the same is not better. There's a development and testing cost, and there's limited portability. Generally, it's not a good idea to reinvent the standard library, and advice to avoid it at all costs is stupid.

Comment: "system-specific DIY code" -That's exactly what using `system()` is. "... the standard library ... and advice to avoid it at all costs is stupid" remember `gets()`? I do like the word balderdash though.

Comment: "shell invoked by system() is implementation defined [i.e. system specific]", and your suggested alternatives are even more so. That's outlandishly invalid logic to me. I do understand that a great many SO readers at least pretend to agree with such things, just in order to belong to a group of like-minded folks, and that evidently my herd instinct is abnormally weak, but still: when did basic logic go out of fashion?

Comment: Or are  you maintaining that in Windows there exists a compiler whose `system` function invokes some other shell than `cmd.exe` or the shell specified by `COMSPEC` variable? If so then please name it.

Comment: It is system specific to an extent, but I chose my wording because you can use different implementations of a C++ compiler on the same system which do things very differently. You're completely correct that many discredit `system()` without understanding why. Yes it's useful for saving three or four lines of code, or for beginners who have not yet learned how to invoke external programs. I fail to see it's usefulnesness given it's limitations beyond that. I'm open to suggestions to better this answer, if you have any.

Comment: AFAIK no Windows compiler do `system` differently than the OS vendor's compiler, Visual C++. I.e., as I see it that's pure FUD. A compiler that did things different than the major OS convention (and that includes `system`, arguments of `main`, etc.) would simply not be used for serious works. That's why I doubt such beast exists, in spite of your indication that it does; and even if it should exist, e.g. some hobbyist's monstrosity, it would not affect advice about using `system`.

Answer (score 0):

The "&& pause" should be part of the string, so it should look like this:

```
std::string s2 = "yara64 -r test.yara " + standardString + "&& pause";

system(s2.c_str());
```